# Visual C++: Good way to draw and animated fill path to screen?

Tags: winapi, animation, geometry, fill, graphic

I want to use Visual C++ to animate fill paths to screen. I have done it with C# before, but now switch to C++ for **better perfomance** and want do **more complex works** in the future.

**Here is the concept in C#:**

In a `Canvas` I have a number of `Path`. These paths are closed geometries combine of `LineTo` and `QuadraticBezierTo` functions.

1. Firstly, I fill Silver color for all path.
2. Then for each path, I fill Green color from one end to other end (up/down/left/right direction) (imagine a progress bar increase its value from min to max). I do it by set the Fill brush of the path to a `LinearGradientBrush` with two color Green and Silver with same offset, then increase the offset from 0 to 1 by Timer.
3. When a path is fully green, continue with next path.
4. When all path is fill with Green, come back first step.

**I want to do same thing in Visual C++. I need to know an effective way to:**

1. Create and store paths in a collection to reuse. Because the path is quite lot of point, recreate them repeatly take lots of CPU usage.
2. Draw all paths to a window.
3. Do animation fill like step 2, 3, 4 in above concept.

**So, what I need is:**

- A suitable way to create and store closed paths. Note: paths are combine of points connect by functions same with C# `LineTo` and `QuadraticBezierTo` function.
- Draw and animated fill the paths to screen.

Can you please suggest one way to do above step? (outline what I have to read, then I can study about it myself). I know basic of Visual C++, Win32 GUI and a little about draw context (HDC) and GDI, but only start to learn Graphic/Drawing.

Sorry about my English! If anythings I explain dont clear, please let me know.

Comment: So, essentially, you are trying to prematurely optimize code you haven't even written yet? Why not write the code, profile it, and then come back when profiling has identified any bottlenecks?

Comment: @IInspectable I already written it nearly an year ago, and it work. I also spent a lot of time optimize it (the CPU usage is 8 - 10%)  But the main of it is functions I list above. And it is about serveral page of code. I think if I post full of the code here it look like I'm asking people convert my code for me, so I don't. If you want to see, I can post it. I want do it by native C++, one reason is I want to learn graphics drawing, wich I know I can do much more complex work compare to C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many is `quite lot of point` ? what is the target framerate? for low enough counts you can use **GDI** for this otherwise you need HW acceleration like **OpenGL,DirectX**.

I assume 2D so You need:

1. **store your path as list of segments**

   for example like this:

   ```
   struct path_segment
    {
    int p0[2],p1[2],p2[2]; // points
    int type; // line/bezier
    float length; // length in pixels or whatever
    };
   const int MAX=1024;     // max number of segments
   path_segment path[MAX]; // list of segments can use any template like List<path_segment> path; instead
   int paths=0; // actual number of segments;
   float length=0.0; // while path length in pixels or whatever
   ```
2. **write functions to load and render `path[]`**

   The render is just for visual check if you load is OK ... for now atlest
3. **rewrite the render so**

   it take `float t=<0,1>` as input parameter which will render path below `t` with one color and the rest with other. something like this:

   ```
   int i;
   float l=0.0,q,l0=t*length; // separation length;
   for (i=0;i<paths;i++)
    {
    q=l+path[i].length;
    if (q>=l0)
     {
     // split/render path[i] to  <   0,l-l0> with color1
     // split/render path[i] to  <l-l0,q-l0> with color2
     // if you need split parameter in <0,1> then =(l-l0)/path[i].length;
     i++; break;
     }
    else
     {
     //render path[i] with color1
     }
    l=q;
    }
   for (;i<paths;i++)
    {
    //render path[i] with color2
    }
   ```
4. **use backbuffer for speedup**

   so render whole path with color1 to some bitmap. On each animation step just render the newly added color1 stuff. And on each redraw just copy the bitmap to screen instead of rendering the same geometry over and over. Of coarse if you have zoom/pan/resize capabilities you need to redraw the bitmap fully on each of those changes ...

Comment: The backbuffer is good idea! Never think of that. Assume I render the path to bitmap, for example with **Silver color**, First step I draw all bitmap to screen, after that I draw parts of each bitmap by timer, so I have to deal with the **overlap** of bitmaps *(each path can overlap eachother, but I must not draw the white rectangle a round the path of the bitmap to screen)* and draw these parts with **Green color**. For draw bitmap I know `BitBlt` but don't know how to avoid draw the white color to screen, and how to draw Silver color bitmap to Green color.Could you point me 2 these function?

Comment: And for more info, the frame rate is one draw/10 miliseconds, the size of whole draw area is 160x160px, with have 20 - 80 paths, each path contains 30 - 50 points, Total duration from 1 second to 1 minute

Comment: @Sakura you do not need to mask anything in back buffer. At first render it with silver (the whole path) and on each timer render the green path that has been added as already traveled (not the whole thing just the incremental step) that should be fast enough ... you do not need the `BitBlt` ... you can render lines and bezier directly with GDI no need for pixel access

Comment: Yes, that is good point. What I consider is the first step, when I have to render all (for example 80) paths to screen at one time *(something like placeholder, indicate user that each path will be draw at which position, imagine a book for kid pratice writing, each character will have a dim shap for kid to follow)*. Ah, I just think maybe this first step I render it to bimap alone, then when finish a circle I draw it to screen. Now the problem solved, many thanks for your help :)